# how to make dynamic year in select option

Tags: php

pls help me how could i make a dynamic year inside the select option. 
heres my code and this one gives me a result of separated year. how could i make the result just in one select option?

```
 $yrnw = date("Y");
 $lyr = 1;
$lstyr = $yrnw - $lyr ;
$sy = 10 + $yrnw;

 for($i=$yrnw; $i<$sy ; $i++){
$lst = $i -1;                   
echo "<tr><td>SY:</td></tr><tr><td><select name= 'sy'>
<option value=''>$lst-$i<br/></option>
"; }
```

Comment: @Antony... its $yrnw.... the current year,... but thanks for responding... i got my answer already from Explosion Pills..

Answer (score 3):

Move the `echo "<tr><td>SY:</td></tr><tr><td><select name= 'sy'>` to *before* the `for` loop.

```
echo "<tr><td>SY:</td></tr><tr><td><select name= 'sy'>";
for ($i=$yrnw; $i<$sy ; $i++) {
    $lst = $i -1;                   
    echo "<option value=''>$lst-$i<br/></option>";
} 
 echo "</select></td></tr>";
```

Comment: what about the value... i want to assign not year but an integer number like 1-10, how could i do it?

Comment: @PotPot perhaps use `date('y')`

Comment: ah ok, but is it ok to have like this "value='$lst-$i'" ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills +1 for being a bro

Comment: @PotPot I guess it's okay, but you should put something in the `value` attribute.  Maybe `<option value='$i'>$lst-$i</option>`

Comment: @ExplosionPills...ah ok... does it change if we are now in year 2014?... i tested it and it save to my table in database as 2013..

Comment: `date('Y')` will be 2013 for the rest of the year.